# iOS UIPickerView custom row view width wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview, custom-view

Return a custom view for the following method to customize the picker row:

```
public override func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    return PickerAccessoryView.instantiateFromNib()
}
```

and returning to be full width:

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return pickerView.frame.width
}
```

Does not resize the row view :O

Answer (score 2):

Solved by setting the initial frame of the custom view to .zero:

```
public override func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let view = PickerAccessoryView.instantiateFromNib()
    view.frame = .zero
    return view
}
```